# MATLAB: How to convert data from an excel file (several sheets) to a matrix?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, cell, xlsread

I try to process data from an excel file from several sheets (~200). Luckily the data is always at the same position in each sheet. I wrote the following code for this purpose which unfortunately does not work since I have problems with converting the cell entries to a matrix. Any idea how to solve that? Thanks!

````
[~, sheet_name] = xlsfinfo('mydata.xlsx');

for k=1:numel(sheet_name)
    
  data{k}=xlsread('mydata.xlsx',sheet_name{k},'A7:A14');
    b{k}=cell2mat(data{k}) %this line does not work...
 
  
end```
````

Comment: What is the error message?

Errors that could be the cause:
As a starter you are indexing b with curly brackets. For a matrix you have to use normal brackets.

Did you initialize b before indexing to it?

Comment: The error is actually not very helpful, it only says: error in line XXX. For the variable data{k} I get a a 1x200 cell, and in each cell I have 7 entries (--> A7:A14). But separating these entries into different rows is does not work with `cell2mat`. Maybe `cell2mat` is not the correct command? I just tried to initialize b before the loop `b = zeros(7,numel(sheet_name));` and I also tried normal brackets for b and it did not work. Do you have  any other idea? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the cell2mat command on the whole cell.

```
data{k}
```

will already give you a matrix that contains the 7 entries of the sheet k.

You either need to use cell2mat on the whole cell after the loop:

```
b=cell2mat(data)
```

or

```
b(k)=data{k}
```

within the loop.